# How to identify if Webpsphere JVM is in "running" state through shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix, websphere, websphere-8

I have a WebSphere JVM that usually took time(not any fix time but between 15-30 mins) to come up, some time 30+ mins. I am scheduling the restart through shell script using cron.

The problem is that I am not understanding how to put it in shell script that if the JVM come up in "running" state then an email will be send. I am clear about how to send email but I am figuring out how to know if JVM came in "running" state. As we know when the script will go for JVM start it will create an PID for that JVM but that really do not mean that JVM is up unless "running" state come.

./serverStauts.sh -all | grep JVM | grep running  _ If i am doing this it will print if its running or not. But i want to know the moment at which JVM came upthat an email will be send at that moment of time .So,  Any way ? Or some suggestion nearby

Comment: If you are using the startServer.sh script provided with websphere to start the JVM, it will not show the prompt until the JVM has come up fully. You can also do "echo $?" to see whether its 0 (success) or not.

Comment: But I am trying to know the moment the JVM come in "running" state automatically . I can do a test after half hour to check if it came running or not. But suppose it came up on 15 mins or it took some time more than 30 mins. Then there will be a confusion.

Comment: Yes this command will exit only after the JVM has come up. You don't have to explicitly find if the server is running or not

Comment: You can do "./startServer.sh JVM && ./sendEmail.sh" where sendEmail is your custom script to send email

Comment: Ok.Correct me if I am wrong. You want to say under the shell script file. If I am putting

./startServer.sh JVM 
echo "Server Started"

Then echo statement will execute only when the JVM get started ?

Comment: Yes you got it right

Comment: Thanks. let me try it now.Will update status  here in next 15-20 mins if worked under that.

Comment: Yeah its good. Thanks again.

Comment: By the way, 15-30min is too much time for starting the AppServer, I would suggest to increase JVM heap size.

Comment: @DYangu Everytime 1 hung thread is generating because of that its taking long time to start .  I am analysing the issue to fix.